# How to get body measurements using height and a photograph in IOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have a requirement to develop and IOS app where I should be able to get the body measurements of a person by using the photograph and the height of the person.I am looking for something like TailorMeasure app in itunes. Please guide me on this.

Comment: Your main difficulty here is going to be determining the height of the person in pixels, apart from the background. From there you can calculate a value for distance per pixel. Then it's just a matter of counting. To achieve this I'd suggest using an updown, leftright iteration through the pixels of an image and then seeing if the colour of any pixel varies by more than a couple of standard deviations away from the mean of the nearest 20x20 block, chances are that's the top of the head. How to code that I have no idea

Comment: is there any reference code?